# bash replace variable name in string with variable value

Tags: bash, sed, replace

This is kind of a weird one. I have the following string:

I have a variable called REDIRECT set to: `https://working.${MYDOMAIN}/blah/blah`.

I need to replace the ${MYDOMAIN} with the actual value of the variable assigned to ${MYDOMAIN}.
Not sure if bash or sed is best for this. I tried bash replace but couldn't get it to work, probably related to escaping the characters or something. Any help appreciated!

Comment: This looks like a XY problem, is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this bash substitution:

```
echo "${REDIRECT/\${MYDOMAIN\}/$MYDOMAIN}"
```

or else, if you have `envsubst` utility then use:

```
export MYDOMAIN
envsubst <<< "$REDIRECT"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just execute in bash:

```
eval REDIRECT=$REDIRECT
```

Comment: And let's pray that this eval won't fall in the wrong hands. Well, much better not to trust it.

Comment: `eval` tends to be unpredictable and unsafe unless you have good control over the data being evaluated. For example, does your URL have any `&` characters (i.e. multiple parameters) in it? If so, that'll be treated as a delimiter between separate shell commands rather than just part of a string.